# Android mutableStateOf() value property not changing

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, data-class

I have a data class.

```
data class ServiceInfoState(
  val availableServices : List<Services> = emptyList(),
  val loadingState : AvailableServicesState = AvailableServicesState.Loading
  )
```

In my view model I keep the state as such:

```
private val _uiState = mutableStateOf(ServiceInfoState())
val uiState : State<ServiceInfoState> = _uiState
```

Later I create a new updated list of services and want to update the state.

```
_uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(availableServices = updated)
```

It is my understanding that this will create a new shallow copy of uiState.value, update the available services list, and assign this to the private property _uiState.value. This change to the value property should cause the UI which is watching the publicly exposed version uiState to recompose. This does not happen.

I then check the code like this:

```
println("List Equality: ${_uiState.value.availableServices === updated}")
val before = _uiState.value
_uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(availableServices = updated)
val after = _uiState.value
println("State Equality: ${before === after}")
```

Which prints out:

```
List Equality: false
State Equality: true
```

I agree that the list is not equal. That was my intention. To have a distinct list just in case. What surprises me is that the value property is equal before and after the copy. Doesn't copy return a new shallow reference? Is this not how this update should occur?

So I see why I am not getting a recomposition. Compose does not see the value property change because it did not change. How do I get it to change?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Define `Services` class, current `availableServices` and `updated`

Comment: @PhilipDukhov `Services` is a data class containing publicly exposed string properties. current `availableServices` is an empty list initially. updated is a `List` with two `Services` elements.  Sorry if this is still not clear. Fundamentally, is the design pattern I've used common for Android, specifically Jetpack Compose? I've watched a lot of tutorials and they all seem to use this strategy. If I pass in the `neverEqualPolicy()` parameter to the `mutableListOf` function then it works. But I don't see why that should be required. Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: I tried reproducing your logs with empty -> non empty list, and I've got double `false`,  that's why I'm asking for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I think I need to construct a better minimal reproducible example as you requested so I do not waste your time. Perhaps I will compose a better question and re-submit that.

Comment: Sure, but there's no need in creating a new question, just edit this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SnapshotMutationPolicy** to control how the result of **mutableStateOf** report and merge changes to the state object. Take a look at my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74301717/8389251