# _uiState.value = uiState.value.copy() don't cause recompose

Tags: android, kotlin, state, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

There is some unresolved situation that happens with my code,
my target is to change the property of an item in the "devices" list (update a boolean),
The change should cause recompose of the view, but that doesn't happen,
In addition, I can see that the item indeed changes with the debugger, but it also causes to add an additional item(an old copy without the included change) to show up in my list.

Is there any idea how I was wrong with the new value assignment?

The ViewModel

```
private val _uiState = mutableStateOf(BTPairingState())
val uiState: State<BTPairingState> get() = _uiState
```

This is how i edit the item in the list

```
    if (handlerDeviceResponse.status != null) {            
        viewModelScope.launch {
            uiState.value.devices.find { it.macAddress == handlerDeviceResponse.device.macAddress }?.isConnected = handlerDeviceResponse.status
            _uiState.value = uiState.value.copy()
        }
    }
```

BTPairingState:

```
data class BTPairingState (
    val devices: MutableList<BtDeviceItemUiModel> = mutableListOf(),
    val deviceType: DeviceType = DeviceType.RFID,
)
```

The Data class

```
data class BtDeviceItemUiModel(
    val name: String,
    val macAddress : String,
    var isConnected: Boolean = false
)
```

The Screen:

```
@Destination
@Composable
fun BTPairScreen(
    viewModel: BTPairViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {

    val state = viewModel.uiState
    BTPairDevices(state.value.devices) { viewModel.deviceItemClicked(it) }
```

Comment: You are not changing any property or something else with _uiState.value = uiState.value.copy() so why should it be recomposed?

Comment: @HamedGord I tried this but ended with the same result:

val list = uiState.value.devices
                list.find { it.macAddress == handlerDeviceResponse.device.macAddress }?.isConnected = handlerDeviceResponse.status
                _uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(devices = list)

Answer (score 4):

Replace `var isConnected` by `val isConnected`.

Then, replace `val devices: MutableList<BtDeviceItemUiModel> = mutableListOf()` by `val devices: List<BtDeviceItemUiModel> = emptyList()`.

IOW, stop using mutable values *inside* of your state.

Then, you can revise your code to update your `MutableState` with a new value, using something like:

```kotlin
    if (handlerDeviceResponse.status != null) {            
            val newDevices = uiState.value.devices.map { device ->
              if (device.macAddress == handlerDeviceResponse.device.macAddress) {
                device.copy(isConnected = handlerDeviceResponse.status)
              } else {
                it
              }
            }
            _uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(devices = newDevices)
    }
```

Comment: Glad to meet you @CommonsWare here! you have a lot of reputations :)

Comment: Thank you a lot!
your replay really help me understand and solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your viewmodel Change state to StateFlow

```
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(BTPairingState())
val uiState: StateFlow<BTPairingState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
```

In your BTPairScreen Instead of

```
val state = viewModel.uiState
```

Use:

```
val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer
val state can't use .collectAsState()
it's already  like this: val uiState: State<BTPairingState> get() = _uiState

Comment: :\ I meant in your BTPairScreen not view model

Comment: sorry for being not clear- I also speak about BTPairScreen

Comment: I've updated the answer. Have you tried it? what is the problem?

Comment: It's already State, so there isn't methos collectAsState

Comment: Convert it to StateFlow and let me know the result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246719/discussion-between-hamed-gord-and-shahar-keysar).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a policy to control how the result of **mutableStateOf** report and merge changes to the state object.

If you writes:

```
private val _uiState = mutableStateOf(BTPairingState(), neverEqualPolicy())
```

every write to _uiState.value will trigger recomposition, but you should of course consider pros and cons of such behavior. You can read more here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/SnapshotMutationPolicy